# Как делать выборку в Django по названию поля, записанному в переменную

Tags: python, django

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли как-нибудь подставить значение из переменной в запрос в ORM Django? Например вот так:

```py
filter_fields = ['width', 'height', 'weight']

products = Product.objects.all()

for param in request.GET:
    if param in filter_fields:
        param_values = request.GET.get(param).split(';')
        products = products.filter(param__in=param_values)
```

Чтобы вместо param__in каждый раз подставлялось текущее значение - width__in, height__in и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
products = Product.objects.all()
for param in request.GET:
    if param in filter_fields:
        param_name = param + '__in'
        param_values = request.GET.get(param).split(';')
        kw = {param_name: param_values}
        products = products.filter(**kw)
```

Или даже короче

```
kw = {(k + '__in'): v.split(';') for k, v in request.GET.items() if k in filter_fields}
products = Product.objects.filter(**kw)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)